# Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game, how can I understand it?

Tags: model-theory, game-theory, first-order-logic

My course of "Formal Methods" deals with Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games, particularly regarding the inexpressibility in FO logic.

At the moment I've fully understand what this games are and how they are supposed to work.
But I can't grasp several theorems regarding inexpressibility, probably because I lack certain basic concepts.

I've tried to read the 2nd chapter of "Elements of Finite Model Theory" by Leonid Libkin but I failed at it quite prominently.

So which are the main concepts I have to understand before directly tackling Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games? Are there any prominent sources out there?

Comment: It would help if you said what exactly did you not understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I learned about Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games from the wonderful, informal notes of Prof. Moschovakis, which can be found [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/lnl.pdf). These notes are used in the first-year graduate logic sequence at UCLA, so they don't assume too much in the way of background. In fact, these games were covered in the first quarter of the class, so I do not believe it was necessary to be familiar with anything more than elementary first-order logic and model theory.